# A third order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following third order ODE.

$$f''' + (c^2-1)f' + \frac{1}{2}f^2 = 0$$

I tried the substitution $f'=w$ to reduce the order of the ODE which gives

$$w^2 \frac{d^2w}{df^2} + w \left(\frac{dw}{df}\right)^2 + (c^2 - 1)w + \frac{1}{2}f^2 = 0$$

but I am not sure if I am on the right track. Any ideas? Thank you.